# Issues with SQLite library and I-Jetty web server

Tags: android, jetty, android-sqlite, ijetty

I have I-Jetty web server configured in Android. I also have a SQLite `.db` file stored in the SD card.

What I want to do is to access my database from a `.WAR` file deployed in the web server.

To do this, I use JDBC library in my servlet to connect to my database. I have added the `.jar` driver file for SQLite. Everything seems to be OK in my development.

The problem is, when I start my web server from Android and access to my servlet within the browser in my device:

```
 http://localhost:8080/myServlet
```

I have this exception raised:

> SQLite library not found.

I don't know why. The SQLite library is normally brought with the Android System, and I have `libsqlitejdbc.so` in my driver file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native SQLite library that comes with Android is integrated in a different way compared to sqlite-jdbc. So sqlite-jdbc can not use it. sqlite-jdbc comes with multiple shared libraries for Windows, Mac and Linux but those are not compatible with Android.

You could use [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) for accessing your DB on your Android device.

Comment: It worked, I can acces my Databse, but i'm not able to do changes on
it using SQL Statment.